# create a function in python to convert form keys into three diferrent json objects

Tags: python, json, forms

I want to make this function return three converted json objects with respective keys:
e.g. : json_obj, json_onj_1, json_obj_2

```
def convert_form_to_json_object(self, form, keys_to_ignore=None):
  json_obj = {}
  for key in form:
    if keys_to_ignore is not None:
        if key not in keys_to_ignore:
            json_obj[key] = form[key]
    else:
        json_obj[key] = form[key]

return json_obj
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I want to take the keys of form and convert them to json key but as you can see here I'm converting only to one json object, so I want to convert form to three diferent objects

Comment: And now? Don't you know how to return multiple objects? (`return obj1, obj2, obj3` would be the solution; it returns a tuple).  Or what is it? Am I blind?

Comment: yeah you're right in how to return them, but how to convert the keys of form to the respective object e.g. obj['key']=form['key'] or how

Comment: I.... don't get what you need. Honestly.

Comment: To help us understand your need, please provide a short, complete program (not a program fragment as above) that demonstrates your problem. Please include sample input, the actual output produced, and what you expected the output to be. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "converted json object"? Are you passing JSON strings as HTTP form values, and you want to decode those strings to the objects they represent? Or…?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your point, but would this help ?

```
def convert_form_to_json_object(self, form, keys_to_ignore=None):
    json_obj = {}
    i = 0
    for key in form:
        k = key + "_" + str(i)  # will append a number to the key
        if keys_to_ignore is not None:
            if key not in keys_to_ignore:
                json_obj[k] = form[key]
        else:
            json_obj[k] = form[key]

    i += 1
    return json_obj
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are asking how to convert a dictionary full of Python objectgs to a dictionary full of JSON objects.

This program creates a dictionary with identical keys to the input dictionary, and JSON objects.

```
import json
def convert_form_to_json_object(form, keys_to_ignore=()):
  json_obj = {}
  for key in form:
    if key not in keys_to_ignore:
      json_obj[key] = json.dumps(form[key])
  return json_obj


x = convert_form_to_json_object({
    'key_the_first':'a string',
    'key_the_second':42,
    'key_the_third':[3.14, 7, 'another string']},
    ('key_the_second'))
print x
```

Result:

```
{'key_the_third': '[3.14, 7, "another string"]', 'key_the_first': '"a string"'}
```

P.s. Sometimes I prefer comprehensions to `for` loops. Here is an alternate version of conversion function:

```
def convert_form_to_json_object(form, keys_to_ignore=()):
  return {key:json.dumps(value)
          for key,value in form.items()
          if key not in keys_to_ignore}
```